# How do I route to a directory?

Tags: fantom, afbedsheet

I'm playing around with afBedSheet and wish to handle all requests to a directory.
eg a request to /abcd calls abcdMethod#doSomething

I have the routes set up as

```
@Contribute { serviceId="Routes" }
static Void contributeRoutes(OrderedConfig conf) {
  conf.add(Route(`/abcd/?`, abcdMethod#doSomething))
}
```

Yet when I browse to /abcd I get 404 errors :(

How do I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure your route handler method `doSomething()` does *NOT* take any arguments. For example, save the following as `Example.fan`:

```java
using afIoc
using afBedSheet

class MyRoutes {
  Text abcdMethod() {
    return Text.fromPlain("Hello from `abcd/`!")
  }
}

class AppModule {
  @Contribute { serviceId="Routes" }
  static Void contributeRoutes(OrderedConfig conf) {
    conf.add(Route(`/abcd/?`, MyRoutes#abcdMethod))
  }
}

class Example {
  Int main() {
    afBedSheet::Main().main([AppModule#.qname, "8080"])
  }
}
```

And run it with:

```
> fan Example.fan -env dev
```

(Appending  `-env dev` will list all available routes on the 404 page.)

Because `/abcd/?` has a trailing `?`, it will match both the file URL of `http://localhost:8080/abcd` and the directory URL of `http://localhost:8080/abcd/`. But note it *will not* match any URLs inside `/abcd`.

To match files inside `/abcd`, add a Uri parameter to your route method (to capture the path) and change your route to:

```
/abcd/**  only matches direct descendants --> /abcd/wotever

/abcd/*** will match subdirectories too   --> /abcd/wot/ever
```

For example:

```java
using afIoc
using afBedSheet

class MyRoutes {
  Text abcdMethod(Uri? subpath) {
    return Text.fromPlain("Hello from `abcd/` - the sub-path is $subpath")
  }
}

class AppModule {
  @Contribute { serviceId="Routes" }
  static Void contributeRoutes(OrderedConfig conf) {
    conf.add(Route(`/abcd/***`, MyRoutes#abcdMethod))
  }
}

class Example {
  Int main() {
    afBedSheet::Main().main([AppModule#.qname, "8080"])
  }
}
```